# Невыполнение Asynctask'a содержащего запрос к Google translate api

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-translate

Пытаюсь отправить текст на перевод посредством AsyncTask'a

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params){

        String trans = params.toString();
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key="+API_KEY+"&q="+ URLEncoder.encode(trans, "UTF-8")+"&source=en&target=de");
            URLConnection urlConnection = null;
            urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));


            //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                total.append(line);
            }
            //transres=total.toString();
            //res=transres(57);
            String tmp = total.toString();
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(tmp);
            JSONObject translated = new JSONObject(data.getString("data"));

            trans = translated.getString("translations");
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(trans);
            JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
            //result=obj.getString("translatedText");
            trans = (jObj.getString(TAG_TRANSLATE));
            Log.d("data", trans);
            text = trans;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return trans;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //txt.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Но к сожалению программа наткнувшись на вызов класса заходит в него только чтобы выполнить onpreExecute, а затем продолжает выполнять все последующие за вызовом класса строки. 
Основной класс, вызывающий переводящий, задается так -

```
public class ChatActivityEnterView extends FrameLayoutFixed implements NotificationCenter.NotificationCenterDelegate, SizeNotifierFrameLayout.SizeNotifierFrameLayoutDelegate
```

Подскажите как заставить таск работать или переводить сразу в UI потоке.
[Собственно сам java файл кода - вызов на строке 835, реализация с 854](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5kb_sW3Xs00Rlh2bS0yU3hwUUE/view?usp=sharing):

```
public void sendMessage() 
{
    if (parentFragment != null) 
    { /**какой-то там код*/ 
    String message = messageEditText.getText().toString();
    text = message; 
    String url = Translate.DEFAULT_BASE_URL; 
    String key = API_KEY; String target = "ru"; 
    String source = "en"; 
    new MyTask().execute(text); 
    if (processSendingText(message)) { /*обновление UI*/ } 
}
```

Comment: Покажите код коим вы задачу вызываете.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб прикрепил файлом. Уж очень много там кода.

Comment: Не, файлом  не надо. Просто привелите строки кода за это отвечающие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось гораздо проще, при выполнении AsyncTask'a основной код тоже выполнялся, и казалось что таск не работает, решилось все сперва командой onPause, пока таск не вернет завершение, а потом и вовсе переносом в функцию где останавливать ничего не надо.